# delete table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td><button>delete</delete></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td><button>delete</delete></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to use JQuery to install a click handler on the delete buttons such that it deletes the current row when clicked

Comment: Offtopic: you've got multiple buttons with the same id - ids should be unique, use a class instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a class of, for example, "delete" to the delete buttons, then use this:

```
$("button.delete").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Alternatively, if you can't add the class, you can use the `:contains` selector:

```
$("button:contains('delete')").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();  
});
```

**Update** (now that the code in the question has completely changed)

Now that you have changed the code in the question to contain only one button instead of two, you don't need to bother adding the `class`, or using the `:contains` selector, you can just use the plain old `button` selector:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. As a side not you should not have same `id` to any dom element on the page.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

In your markup the tags are not closed properly. E.g the button tag is not closed properly so the selector will not work. Give a unique id or a class name to select the required buttons.

Something like this

```
 <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td>Some content</td>
    <td><input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" /></td>
  </tr>
```

Using `delegate` to attach event handler only to table for better performance. This way the `click` event will be attached only to the table element no matter how many rows it has.

```
$("table").delegate("input.delete", "click", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try soemthing like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td><img class="delete" src="del.gif" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td><img class="delete" src="del.gif" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And your jQuery:

```
$('table td img.delete').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, there's a syntax error in your HTML, and you should a class identifier for easier access to those buttons:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td><button class="delete">delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>foo</td>
    <td><button class="delete">delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Next, here's the jQuery code you need:

```
$(function() {
    $('button.delete').click(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();    
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, looks like a few of us were answering at the same time... I got sidetracked and posted mine late